# case statment for non ONE TO ONE value

Tags: case, clause

I wrote a query with case statment but I have a problem with non ONE-TO-ONE results.
In particulare:

case when Prova1=Prova2 then "ok"
else "no"
end

I wuold like how to order the column used in case statment in order to take the right value (see the example)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwGtw.png)

find a work around